# How can I use java code to compile java file in other folder?

Tags: java, process, compilation, javac

I am trying to use Java's

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

to compile **.java files** in other folder, but it does not work.
My **Main.class** is in folder **a**, and all **.java files** are in folder **a/test**.

**Main.class is :**

```
public class Main{
    public static void main( String[] args )
                throws IOException,InterruptedException{
        String line ="";
        String command = "javac test/*.java";
        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader( pro.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        BufferedReader er = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader( pro.getErrorStream()));
        while ((line = er.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

And the error stream shows:

```
javac: file not found: test/*.java
```

Why does this happen?  There are some java file in folder test

Answer (score 1):

1. in this case Java doesn't work with * as wildcard, as well as your shell. 
   That means that you would transform * -> list of file_names manually and do exec() for every particular file.
2. Also be aware on classpath. if you run this class form IDE, classpath could be different from you expect (same folder in which class is placed).

Comment: but why it works if the Main class is in the same folder as other java file? like javac *.java

Comment: @Jianson: Actually it is working just fine. Have you added `javac` to the `PATH` variable?

Comment: @nIcEcOw : Yes, I added it.  After I run Main.class, there is no class file in test folder....

Comment: @Jianson: On my side, your code is working just fine (.class files are generated inside the said folder ), though only if I use somethingy like `String command = "javac -d . ../test/SomeClass.java";` instead of asterisk.